# Proxy service giving error "Connection time out after request is read"

Tags: wso2, esb

We have created proxy service in wso2 esb using esb project in eclipse.

We have two web service calls and a data mapper.

proxy service is giving error "2017-02-23 12:06:32,131 [-] [HTTP-Listener I/O dispatcher-4]  WARN SourceHandler Connection time out after request is read: http-incoming-40 Socket Timeout : 180000 Remote Address : /10.65.0.75:52864" as we add data mapper.

Without data mapper proxy service is running successfully. some times it also runs successfully with data mapper.

can someone guide about this issue?

Following is the proxy source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationPS"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap11"
                        uri="http://10.1.6.175:9763/services/EslSfaOMSODataService.SOAP11Endpoint/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="full"/>
         <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationMapping.dmc"
                     inputSchema="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationMapping_inputSchema.json"
                     inputType="XML"
                     outputSchema="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationMapping_outputSchema.json"
                     outputType="XML"/>
         <log description="" level="full"/>
         <header name="Authorization"
                 scope="transport"
                 value="Basic --"/>
         <log level="full"/>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap11"
                        uri="https://oraclefusionhost:443/soa-infra/services/default/DooDecompReceiveOrderExternalComposite/ReceiveOrderRequestService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="full"/>
         <drop/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

calling proxy through scheduled task, attached is the source

```
<task class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector"
        group="synapse.simple.quartz" name="testtask2">
        <trigger count="1" interval="60"/>
        <property name="proxyName" value="EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationPS" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
        <property name="soapAction" value="operation" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
        <property name="injectTo" value="proxy" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"/>
        <property name="message" xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks">
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:esl="esl" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soapenv:Header/>
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <esl:operation/>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </property>
    </task>
```

Secondly how can we have the response from proxy service. our web-service create record in db and return status success when run stand alone form soap ui.

Comment: post your synapse configuration

Comment: statistics.clean.interval=1000

synapse.observers=org.wso2.carbon.mediation.dependency.mgt.DependencyTracker

synapse.commons.json.preserve.namespace=false

synapse.temp_data.chunk.size=3072

synapse.carbon.ext.tenant.info=org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.handler.CarbonTenantInfoConfigurator
synapse.carbon.ext.tenant.info.initiator=org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer.handler.CarbonTenantInfoInitiator

synapse.xpath.func.extensions=org.wso2.carbon.mediation.security.vault.xpath.SecureVaultLookupXPathFunctionProvider

Comment: synapse.debugger.port.command=9005
synapse.debugger.port.event=9006

mediation.flow.statistics.enable=false
mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.payloads=false
mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.properties=false
mediation.flow.statistics.event.consume.interval=1000
mediation.flow.statistics.event.clean.interval=15000

mediation.flow.statistics.collect.all=false

Comment: actually by `synapse configurations` i meant the synapse source of your proxy.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationPS"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap11"
                        uri="http://10.1.6.175:9763/services/EslSfaOMSODataService.SOAP11Endpoint/"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="full"/>

Comment: <datamapper config="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationMapping.dmc"
                     inputSchema="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationMapping_inputSchema.json"
                     inputType="XML"
                     outputSchema="gov:datamapper/EslSfaOFAOMSOIntegrationMapping_outputSchema.json"
                     outputType="XML"/>
         <log description="" level="full"/>
         <header name="Authorization"
                 scope="transport"
                 value="Basic --"/>
         <log level="full"/>

Comment: <call>
            <endpoint>
               <address format="soap11"
                        uri="https://oraclefusionhost:443/soa-infra/services/default/DooDecompReceiveOrderExternalComposite/ReceiveOrderRequestService"/>
            </endpoint>
         </call>
         <log level="full"/>
         <drop/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>

Comment: Please update the question with complete one.

Comment: I have updated the question with source.
But it runs successfully if i remove data mapper from esb project. I faced same issue yesterday, however it started working fine automatically. now i am facing "Connection time out after request is read" again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `<drop/>` with a `<respond />`

Comment: Proxy service is giving error "Unexpected error sending message back {org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport out has not been set" while using respond.

Comment: how do you call the proxy?

Comment: calling proxy through scheduled task. updating the scheduled task source in question.

Comment: in that case, you shouldn't have `respond`. you should have `OUT_ONLY` just before last `call`, as i mentioned in the previous question.

Comment: yes removing respond solved the error "Unexpected error sending message back" but as i have mentioned, i want the proxy service to return the status. how would it return.

Comment: how do you plan to use that returned status? the tasks do not expect a response. so whatever you're planning to do with that status, you have to do within the proxy itself.